# AWK is not producing an output when used in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$dd="/root/report/lastDate-28-11-2013.csv";
$c_row=exec("awk 'BEGIN { FS = \",\" } ; { print $1 }'" .$dd);
//echo $c_row;
print_r($c_row); 
?>
```

When i run this code it simply hangs and does not print any output.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), you're missing an `output` and/or `return_var` parameter.

To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.

Syntax:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

> **output**
>
> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
> whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
> the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
> end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
> call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
>
> **return_var**
>
> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be
> written to this variable.

In your case, it might look something like...

```
$csv = "/your/file.csv"; 
$comm = "awk 'BEGIN { FS = \",\" } ; { print $1 }'" .$dd;
exec($comm, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

(I haven't checked your `awk` command so far, I suspect it returns the desired result)

Comment: can you please provide the syntax how should i use description given by you in script.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a short sample adapted from your code.